# window.location opening links in a new tab

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, window.open, window.location

So far I have

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 47%; top: 70%; margin-right: -52%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)" onclick="window.location='https://steamcommunity.com/';">
```

I want to open this page in a new tab, but have issues using window.open since the class is an image. Any Suggestions?

Comment: How exactly have you tried using `window.open`? What do you mean by _“since the class is an image”_?

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead target="_blank":

```
<a href="https://steamcommunity.com/'"  target="_blank"/>
```

Comment: I'm not using a href, i'm using window.location, and I can't specify a target for some reason